# Sum double values from Json Array

Tags: java, json

I am using this code after alot of search

```
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++){
JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);
String txN_AMT = jsonObject2.optString("txN_AMT").toString();

double totalAmount = 0.0;

totalAmount = totalAmount + Double.parseDouble(txN_BAL_AMT);

Toast.makeText(TenantDetailsActivity.this, "" + totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but this code will not sum up the values it is showing one by one in toast but why?

My Json response is this

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            
            "txN_AMT": 540.0
            
        },
        {
            
            "txN_AMT": 11250.0
            
        },
        {
            
            "txN_AMT": 11250.0
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: seems like theres something wrong with your for loop, where is the end bracket for it ? your toast (and the rest of your logic) seems to be inside the `for`, i think you missed the ending of the loop

Comment: I forget to add end bracket it is below toast

Comment: it can't be below toast, then it will execute every time the for does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a basis Logical mistake and it has nothing to do with android . You are re initializing `totalAmount` with `0.0` again and again .

```
private void sum() {
    double totalAmount = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i);
        String txN_AMT = jsonObject2.optString("txN_AMT");
        totalAmount = totalAmount + Double.parseDouble(txN_BAL_AMT);
    }
    //outside of the loop, you now have the total amount
    Toast.makeText(TenantDetailsActivity.this, "" + totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```